# How can I use PHP to save the state of a React component in a JSON file?

Tags: php, json, reactjs

I'm studying ReactJS and I'm trying to do a simple online "shopping list" app. Using a form, I submit an input text, I save it in the state, then I show the saved message in the page. However, when I close the page I lose every message I added. So, I would like to use PHP to save the state in a JSON file instead of in the state, and update the state with the JSON file. In this way, even if I close my browser, I don't lose anything.

I want to use PHP because I use it in my website and I have read that React can't write in file, so I thought to use PHP to write in a JSON file, but I don't know how to do. Can you help me, please? This is the code of my app.

```css
.messaggio {
    background-color: #d5f4b5;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.grey {
    background-color: whitesmoke !important;
}
.orario {
    margin-top: 2px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: grey;
}
#chatbox, form {
    max-width: 400px;
}
#messaggi{
    text-align: right;
}
input[type=text] {
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
input[type=submit]{
    width: 60px;
    background-color: silver;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel">

function Messaggio(props) {
    const classe = props.colore ? "messaggio " + props.colore : "messaggio";
    return(
    <div className={classe}>{props.children}</div>
    );
}

function Messaggi(props) {
    const messaggi = props.messaggi;
    const puntini = props.scrivendo ? (<Messaggio colore="grey"><i>...</i></Messaggio>) : '';
    
    const lista = messaggi.map((messaggio,key) =>
        <div key={key}>
        <Messaggio>
        <div>{messaggio.testo}</div>
        <div className="orario">{messaggio.ora}</div></Messaggio>
        </div>
        );
    
    return(
    <div id="messaggi">
        {lista}
        {puntini}
    </div>
    );
}

function Inserimento(props) {
    return(
        <form onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
            <label>
                <input type="text" 
                value={props.testo} 
                onChange={props.onChange}/>
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Invia" />
        </form>
    );
}

class Chatbox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChangeMessaggio = this.handleChangeMessaggio.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmitMessaggio = this.handleSubmitMessaggio.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            messaggi: [],
            testo: '',
        }
    }
    
    handleChangeMessaggio(e) {
        this.setState({
            testo: e.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmitMessaggio(e) {
        const ora = new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' });
        const testo = this.state.testo;
        const newMsg = {testo:testo,ora:ora};
        const messaggi = this.state.messaggi;
        this.setState({
            messaggi: messaggi.concat(newMsg),
            testo: ''
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    
    render(){
        const messaggi = this.state.messaggi;
        const scrivendo = this.state.testo === '' ? false : true;
        return(
            <div id="chatbox">
            <Messaggi messaggi={messaggi} scrivendo={scrivendo} />
            {scrivendo}
            <Inserimento
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmitMessaggio}
            onChange={this.handleChangeMessaggio}
            testo={this.state.testo}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <Chatbox />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

</script>

 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: From time to time you need to send the "draft" form to PHP and store somewhere with some identifier. Whenever the user need to get this "draft" just query for this data and send back to user.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte Thank you. I did some researches about "draft form" and I found what I needed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. onSubmit should store your data somewhere on server (file/db) - use fetch() for example;
2. Please read more about the componentDidMount function - using that function you can load the state from server side using browser fetch(...) function. In the fetch promise fetch().then( ... you can assign the current state using setState())

Answer (score 0):

I want to share how I used your replies to find the solution.

I added a POST send, using XMLHttpRequest in the submit function (handleSubmitMessaggio):

```
var data = new FormData();
var updated_state = messaggi.concat(newMsg);
data.append('value', JSON.stringify(updated_state));
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', window.location, true);
xhr.send(data);
```

Then I added a code to get POST value in PHP and write it in a json.

```
$json = str_replace('\"', '"', $_POST["value"]);

//write json to file
if (isset($_POST["value"])){
file_put_contents("messages.json", $json);
}
```

Finally, I added a componentDidMount function where I call a function that use fetch method to load the json and update the state with it.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.timerMsgs = setInterval(
    () => this.updateMsgs(),
    500
    );
}

updateMsgs() {
    fetch("messages.json?_=" + Date.now())
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            this.setState({
                messaggi: result
            });
        },
        (error) => {
            this.setState({
                error
            });
        }
    )
}
```

Thank you to everyone who replied! ^_^